# HTML/CSS: Trigger actions between cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a table that looks something like this:

```
  __________________________________________
 |__________|__________|____________________|
 |    1     |    4     |     ___________    |
 |__________|__________|    |           |   |
 |    2     |    5     |    |  default  |   |
 |__________|__________|    |  picture  |   |
 |    3     |    6     |    |___________|   |
 |__________|__________|____________________|
```

And for each of the numbers (table cells), I want the hover effect to be something different. For example:

```
  __________________________________________
 |__________|__________|____________________|
 |  **1**   |    4     |     ___________    |
 |__________|__________|    |           |   |
 |    2     |    5     |    |  picture  |   |
 |__________|__________|    |     1     |   |
 |    3     |    6     |    |___________|   |
 |__________|__________|____________________|


  __________________________________________
 |__________|__________|____________________|
 |    1     |    4     |     ___________    |
 |__________|__________|    |           |   |
 |    2     |  **5**   |    |  picture  |   |
 |__________|__________|    |     5     |   |
 |    3     |    6     |    |___________|   |
 |__________|__________|____________________|
```

And so on.

To clarify, I want a default picture to show when the page is first loaded. I want the text each table cell to have a unique corresponding image (1.png, 2.png, etc) and I want each image to be invisible until the corresponding text is hovered over. That is, 3.png only shows when "3" is hovered over, 4.png only shows when "4" is hovered over, and so on. If nothing is being hovered over, the default image shows.

Is there a way to do this using only HTML and CSS?

Here's the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <p>hey</p>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="category">Heading 1</td>
            <td class="category">Heading 2</td>
            <td class="category">Heading 3</td>
            <td class="image" rowspan="2">
                <img src="default.png" alt="default">
                <img src="1.png" alt="1">
                <img src="2.png" alt="2">
                <img src="3.png" alt="3">
                <img src="4.png" alt="4">
                <img src="5.png" alt="5">
                <img src="6.png" alt="6">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="options">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="options">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Sorry for the code dump. I would post my CSS file as well, but it is causing some errors and that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: sadly this is not possible with css and html only. You will have to write some javascript to do this. Lets us know if you need any help with that!

Comment: You mean without javascript? That would be very difficult. Please give some examples of what effects do you expect. Just style changes? With onmouseenter="some javascript" you can achieve almost anything.

Comment: Why not? This is possible with CSS, but with limitations and not this html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a HTML CSS solution:

```css
.main {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image, image,
.options img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 40px;
  right: 70px;
}
.options img{
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover + img {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>hey</p>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="category">Heading 1</td>
            <td class="category">Heading 2</td>
            <td class="category">Heading 3</td>
            <td class="image" rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=default" alt="default">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="options">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>1</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1" alt="1"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>2</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2" alt="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>3</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3" alt="3"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="options">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>4</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=4" alt="4"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>5</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=5" alt="5"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a>6</a><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=6" alt="6"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

I moved the images in the table cells.

Here's a [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6gu0y8sz/1/) just in case...

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I need.